# Short story (maybe an excerpt from a book) about some kids on a farm - simulated bucking bronco and swapped horses at a hoe down

Tags: identification-request, short-stories

I was just recounting this to someone, but as a child, we had a book with various stories, I think primarily about rural people. I have a vague memory of that it might have included the Little House on the Prairie story about them making their way home from school during a snowstorm (I have vivid memories of at least one of the children thinking they'd been struck blind, only to learn that their eyes had been iced shut, and the wetted cloth used to thaw the ice coming away pink due to scratches from the snow), but the story I'm trying to track down had a handful of kids (I don't remember the actual ages) on a farm, and I remember two anecdotes from the story.

- The kids were keen to learn how to ride a bucking bull, or bronco. After they were told off for riding some of the other livestock (I remember text about one of the animals they rode, maybe a sheep, being heavily lathered, and them being remonstrated for that they could have accidentally killed the animal (maybe they weren't normally part of the farm, but were visiting?). So instead, they get a metal barrel, and mount it on ropes attached to four saplings, put a saddle on it, and simulate the bucking by having people shake the saplings. I remember one of the cowboys indicating that it was pretty good, and that he had a hard time staying one when all four were being shaken.
- They attend a hoe down or other party. At some point, they come back to the hitching line, and see that they horses are all tangled together (basically, the horses had shifted around, going under and over their hitching lines). They untie the lines one by one and reattach them where the horse is to "fix" the problem. The next morning, a neighbor walks out of one of the bedrooms, looking bewildered. It turns out that a number of people, too tired or drunk, took the wrong horse "home", having grabbed the horse by position rather than properly identifying it. The horse, of course, went to its home, which didn't correspond to its rider.

I would have read this somewhere in the 1985-1995 time frame, but there's a good chance the book was older. I remember a mix of pen-and-ink drawings (including the bucking bronco simulator) and glossy color illustrations that looked more like oil paintings (one stuck with me over the years with an older fellow with a grey beard with a slightly deranged look on his face as he was captured mid-jig, dancing by the fire with the people he was travelling with, I think in a different story than the others I've mentioned).

Comment: Set in which country/region? I have vague memories of some of the [Silver Brumby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_Brumby) series which this question triggered, but that's set in Australia (and I guess the main characters were horses rather than human kids).

Comment: This was definitely following human kids. My brain says that it was the United States, towards the western part of the country, but that might be because that's where I lived (well, Mid-west for me) so naturally I'd assume all civilized people came from that place at that age. :-D